# How to install wireless dongle driver without internet? (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: wireless, d-link

I downloaded the D-link driver from the website and transferred it on usb to my computer. When running the install.sh file I encounter the error "bash: make: command not found". Since I do not have internet, I cannot download the build-essential package that contains make. What can I do?

Comment: Is it Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 0):

You can install `build-essential` from the Ubuntu installation media. Additional packages are in `pool` directory. It will require some dependencies, that are located there too.

The easiest way is to dump all the packages to some directory and install `build-essential` using `dpkg`.

Installing "D-Link" drivers from their site is not a good idea, but it is a different story for a different question.